# How to create a Flexbox that has dimension arrows on 2 sides with active areas for the dimensions

Tags: css, svg

I have a page that has a view of a box. This has the 2 areas where the arrows are to input the dimension. I am not familiar with the concept below and I am not having any luck placing the arrows where I need them. length etc. and then centering the text part in the middle. I pulled this from somewhere online a long time ago and just got back to it. Does anyone know anything about this or a place I can go for more info? Also it does not play nice with bootstrap. It does not adjust on the screen like everything else. I need it to be responsive.

```css
.shape {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      background: white;
      height: 284px;
      width: 355px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 230px;
    }

    .shape-container {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      width: 400px;
      height: 325px;
      background: Gainsboro;
      padding: 2px;
    }

    svg {
      width: 284px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .svgContainer {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      width: 225px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .svgContainer:after {
        content: attr(data-dimention);
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: -24px;
        padding: 0 8px;
        background-color: Gainsboro;
        color: #8c8b8b;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 20px;
    }

    .svgLeft {
      left: -96px;
      top: 150px;
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    .svgBottom {
      bottom: 8px;
      right: 8px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="shape-container">
        <div class="svgContainer svgLeft" data-dimention="30 mm">
          <svg>
            <marker id="arrow-left" markerHeight="16" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="20" orient="auto" refX="3" refY="0" viewBox="0 -5 20 20">
              <path d="M 15 -5 L 0 0 L 15 5 z" fill="black" />
            </marker>
            <marker id="arrow-right" markerHeight="16" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="20" orient="auto" refX="-3" refY="0" viewBox="-15 -5 20 20">
              <path d="M -15 -5 L 0 0 L -15 5 z" fill="black" />
            </marker>

            <line id="e3_line" x1="0" y1="10" x2="284" y2="10" stroke="black" style="stroke-width: 1px; fill: none; marker-start: url(&quot;#arrow-left&quot;); marker-end: url(&quot;#arrow-right&quot;);" />
         </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="shape">
       shape image
    </div>
    <div class="svgContainer svgBottom" data-dimention="30 mm">
         <svg>
            <marker id="arrow-left" markerHeight="16" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="20" orient="auto" refX="3" refY="0" viewBox="0 -5 20 20">
               <path d="M 15 -5 L 0 0 L 15 5 z" fill="black" />
            </marker>
            <marker id="arrow-right" markerHeight="16" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="20" orient="auto" refX="-3" refY="0" viewBox="-15 -5 20 20">
               <path d="M -15 -5 L 0 0 L -15 5 z" fill="black" />
            </marker>

            <line id="e3_line" x1="0" y1="10" x2="225" y2="10" stroke="black" style="stroke-width: 1px; fill: none; marker-start: url(&quot;#arrow-left&quot;); marker-end: url(&quot;#arrow-right&quot;);" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a picture to the question where the location of the arrows, text relative to the box should be visible

Comment: The lines text and arrow ends should be even with the shape image on the side and bottom measuring the shape image. with the text of the dimensions in the middle of the lines. I am thinking that the container that they are in is hindering the placement. If I try to move the left side of the bottom dimension the arrow head disappears and the line end only moves to a certain point like it is bound to a certain area that i cannot seem to figure out where that is.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my comment. But words are understood in different ways. It would be better to see a drawing of how it should look.

Comment: My apologies I did get this where i needed them but it took a lot of trial and error fudging with the container sizes and line positions.. Now the only thing left is to get it to play nice with boostrap. Which is the original question...